# Is there a way to include an algorithm from external file?

Tags: algorithmic

I mean: when I put some code in my docs I can include it whitout writing all code in main document.

Is there a similar thing for algorithm?

Comment: `\input{fooalgorithm}`?

Comment: yeah.. it works.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the kind of result expected, there are two solutions:

### Input

Using `\input(my_file.tex)` allows you to append the content of my_file.tex to your main TeX file. You can nest `\input` comands inside files you call from your main document.

### Include

Using `\include(my_file.tex)` has the same use but forces a page break and doesn't allow nested `\include`. However, you can still `\input` a file inside the document you want to `\include`.

Note that both commands can be used for any type of LaTeX resource, not only for algorithms. See [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents) for further explanation.

Comment: I don't think `\include` should even be mentioned in this context.

Comment: @egreg Why? Is there a detail I'm missing about `\include` or its behavior?